# fs.writeFileSync TypeError: lazyErrmapGet is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: node.js, gulp, fs, fs-extra

> fs.writeFileSync TypeError: lazyErrmapGet is not a function or its
>   return value is not iterable

I faced this issue while using `fs.writeFileSync` from fs-extra as following inside one of my `gulp task` :

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    `${docsTarget}/content-list.json`,
    JSON.stringify(contentList, null, 4),
    { flag: 'w' },
    'utf8'
 );
```

Now I am not able to reproduce it, but want to know what may be the cause for the same!

Following are the logs:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it comes from returning a non-array to a result expecting an array.  The called function may usually return an array, but has less often used branch where it returns a non-array.

Apparently an iterator returning a non-array can be used to fill an array.  So the runtime Javascript mistakenly thinks that is what is intended.